# Meteor Velocity Mirror does not have data

Tags: meteor-velocity

I'm new to Velocity and am using Mocha as my testing framework. I understand how to writ e the tests and structure, but my mirrored app on port 5000 does not seem to have a replicant of my database. I was wondering is there extra configuration I have to do to get that wired up? All my tests fail, but thats because it has no data to compare off of.

Thank you for the help in advance, and if you need more information then I'm more than happy to provide it.

Answer (score 2):

The mirror intentionally has its own database so you can continue development in the main app, but also have your tests run in the background against the mirror.

What you should do before each test (or before all tests) is setup the state you require in the database. For this you can use fixtures. If you put a file called anyName-fixture.js (or coffee) under your /tests directory, Velocity will make this file accessible in the mirror. This file can then setup the data needed for your tests.

[Click here for an example of a fixture](https://github.com/meteor-velocity/velocity-examples/blob/master/leaderboard-cucumber/tests/fixtures.js).

In your test, you can easily call the fixture using a meteor method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sam. Look forward to reading more of your book! I was wondering, would it be possible to mongorestore data to the mirrored db?

Comment: If you look at [this fixture](https://github.com/meteor-velocity/velocity/blob/b5dada25e18c6bc2ef16fcc64b3d073eb2b6a544/default-fixture.js#L35) it has some low-level access to the DB. Perhaps you could do something similar. The mongorestore would have to run as a command line which is a little cumbersome. 

I would advise you not to copy the main db to the mirror. That sounds like a bad test design to me. You want your tests to have a SETUP / EXECUTE and VERIFY stage. The setup is to make sure you have everything you need for the specific test. 

What testing framework are you using?

Comment: @TheMeteorTestManual The link no longer works. I did get this link from Sanjo from the Google Group.

https://github.com/Sanjo/meteor-jasmine/wiki/Database-Fixtures-for-Integration-Tests

Is this a good example? Also, do you have any examples of what to include inside loadDefaultFixtures()?

Comment: Yes it is a good example. I also just updated the link above to work, thanks for pointing out.